# Редакция неясной части предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

В интернете встретила такой отрывок:

*Компания Sideshow, в сотрудничестве с Legacy Effects  представляет вашему вниманию детскую фигурку в натуральную величину, **чтобы принести вам желанную награду галактики.***

*Таинственный инопланетянин, которого с любовью называют "Малыш Йода", быстро стал фаворитом в "Звездных войнах: Мандалорианец"на Дисней+. Теперь нетерпеливые коллекционеры могут стать кланом из двух человек и **принести домой актив** в виде невероятного предмета коллекционирования «Звездных войн» в масштабе 1:1.*

Предложения звучат не совсем удачно. Как выяснилось, это дословный перевод. И имеются в виду не активы, а, как я поняла, награда. Mandalorian — это bounty hunter (охотник за головами, наемный убийца), который охотится по всей галактике за bounties / assets (цель, добыча, вознаграждение — в зависимости от того, имеется в виду человек, которого нужно убить, или вознаграждение за его убийство). Tracking fob (приводной маячок) — устройство, способное привести охотника прямиком к цели.

*Sideshow presents The Child Life-Size Figure, created in partnership with Legacy Effects to bring you the galaxy’s most sought-after bounty.*

*Lovingly referred to by audiences as ‘Baby Yoda’, the mysterious alien known as The Child has quickly become the breakout fan-favorite of Star Wars™: The Mandalorian on Disney+. Now eager collectors can become a clan of two and bring home the asset as an incredible 1:1 scale Star Wars collectible, no tracking fob needed.*

Вопрос: как грамотно оформить/передать на русском выделенную жирным часть?

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:
1) *Компания Sideshow представляет вашему вниманию детскую фигурку в натуральную величину, созданную в сотрудничестве с Legacy Effects, чтобы вручить (подарить) вам самую (наиболее) востребованную (желанную) галактическую награду.*
2) *взять себе ценную вещь.*